# Migrating parallels PVM from Mac to Windows

Tags: parallels-desktop

I have a Linux image (Parallels v9 PVM file) on my MBP, which I would like to migrate to Windows (to clarify: so that the Linux image can be launched from Windows, instead of from Mac).

Is this possible?  Do I just need to install Parallels on the Windows PC and copy over the .PVM?  Or do I need to use a different tool for the migration?

Comment: Do you want him to run the virtual image? Or what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have made the question more clear!

Answer (score 1):

To launch the PVM under Windows you need Parallels Workstation running on your Windows box. Unfortunately Parallels withdrew that product either later 2013 or early 2014 which is a shame.
I run the Windows product all the time with multiple VMs running (Windows desktop with lots of disk space) and then move the PVM to my MacBook Air (limited disk space)when I have to go to a customer site